# Interaction plots for continuous variables in logistic regression

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression, interaction, sjplot

I fitted a logistic regression  model with a interaction between  continuous predictors.

I used `plot_model()` function in `sjPlot` package in R to get this interaction plots and i couldnt figure out how this function has categorized volume in to 2 factors.

```
require(ISLR)
require(sjPlot)

m1=glm(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag4* Volume ,data=Smarket,family ="binomial" )

plot_model(m1,type = "int",colors =rainbow(3))
```

[image]

0.36 and 3.15 corresponds to the minimum and maximum volume respectively.

**Can anyone help me to interpret this plot ?**

**Also is there any other way to draw this interaction plots for logistic regression ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interaction is between two continuous variables. The plot is using `Lag4` as the x-axis variable and then picking a couple of values of `Volume` to show how the relationship between `Direction` and `Lag4` varies for different values of `Volume`. By default, the minimum and maximum of `Volume` are chosen. You can instead show the median and quartiles of `Volume` or the mean and standard deviation of `Volume` by using the `mdrt.values` argument (see the help for additional options). For example:

```
theme_set(theme_classic()) # Set ggplot theme

plot_model(m1, type="int", colors=rainbow(3), mdrt.values="quart")
plot_model(m1, type="int", colors=rainbow(3), mdrt.values="meansd")
```

[image]

Another option is a heatmap, which would allow you to plot the interaction variables on the x and y axes, and use colour to signify the probability of `Direction` equal to "Up". For example:

```
# Create grid of Lag1 and Volume values for prediction
pred.dat = expand.grid(Lag1 = median(Smarket$Lag1),
                       Lag4 = seq(min(Smarket$Lag4), max(Smarket$Lag4), length=100),
                       Volume = seq(min(Smarket$Volume), max(Smarket$Volume), length=100))

# Add predictions
pred.dat$Direction = predict(m1, newdata=pred.dat, type="response")

# Plot heatmap
ggplot(pred.dat, aes(Lag4, Volume, fill=Direction)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="white", high="blue", 
                       midpoint=median(pred.dat$Direction)) +
  labs(title='Probability of Direction="Up"',
       fill="Probability")
```

The plots above represent lines of constant `Volume` across the heatmap below. For example, when `Volume` is 1.12 (red line in left-hand plot above) you can in the heatmap below see that the colour goes from blue to white to red, signifying decreasing probability of `Direction="Up"` as `Lag4` increases, just as we see in the plot above.

[image]